# How to select an specific sample of time series from a dataframe without losing information

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
|numero_servicio |  Date    | Consumo
|400000154407    |201612    | 0.0
|400000102416    |201306    |144.0
|400000327766    |201706    |0.0
|400000106035    |201701    |264.0
|400000091097    |201802    |142.0
|400000220846    |201409    |110.0
|115264062055    |201901    |217.0
```

As you can see, there a numbers of service under the column named `numero_servicio`  that have a specific value for each date.

What I want to do is get a sample for at least 10 numbers of service without losing any information.

I tried this:

```
muestra = serie_consumo.groupby('numero_servicio').apply(lambda group_df: group_df.sample(2)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

... but what I get is a sample of two values for each number of service.

Can someone tell me how can I do this properly?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want any "numeros de servicio" you can just use `df[x:y]`, which will give you the rows from x to y in your df. If your Dataframe is called "serie_consumo" this will cut out the first 10 rows:

```
sample = serie_consumo[0:9]
```

or if you want some 20 rows (if your DataFrame has enough rows):

```
sample = serie_consumo[450:469]
```

Edit: because its not readable well in the comment:

Could you try this:

```
import pandas as pd
sample=serie_consumo.groupby("numero de servicios")["Date"].apply(list).to_frame()
sample1=serie_consumo.groupby("numero de servicios")["Consumo"].apply(list).to_frame()

sample_grouped = pd.concat([sample, sample1],axis=1, sort=False)
```

Comment: Thank you buth the thing is that each row contains a "numero de servicio" with date and consumo, what i want is to have a  number of "numero de servicios" but with the complete information for that "numero de servicio" , and that means the information with all the dates available for that specific "numero de servicio in the sample

Comment: so for each "numero de servicio" chosen in the sample i shlud have at least 12 rows with the different values for each date. I dont know if I made my self clrear. Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you try the code snippet i edited into the answer and tell me if that is what you were looking for?
Because this way, you should get a dataframe, that will give you the numero de servicios and then a list of all corresponding dates in the column date and a list with all corresponding consumos in the column consumo.
Then you can just sample_grouped[x:y] if you want to only see some numeros de servicio.

Comment: yes I tried it thank you, that can work and as you said after doing that I can get the sample, but after that how I get the initial structure back again? sorry to bother and again thank you very much for your help

Comment: That actually is very helpful but after having that and extracting the sample if I wanna plot for each numero de servicio the time series, how can I do it ?? thank you very much!!!

Comment: If you want to have the initial structure back, I would suggest just saving it at a different name so you have both, so in the example above, you have sample_grouped and numero de servicios as the grouped and original dataset. For the plotting I would suggest the matplotlib, see https://matplotlib.org/ . As it has functions such as matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date() .

Answer (score 0):

I got the all of the dataframe along with the sample when i tried your code.

`df.groupby(['numero_servicio ']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1)).reset_index(drop=True)`

```
    numero_servicio Date    Consumo
0   4.000001e+11    201409  110
1   4.000001e+11    201701  264
2   4.000002e+11    201612  0
3   4.000003e+11    201706  0
```

Please note if you do not have 2 sample per group then your code won't work. I am only using one sample as i have groups with one sample. Are you getting any error saying you cannot sample more than available data?

Comment: I am geeting the samples, but the thing and sorry if I wasn´t clear with the question. What   I want is to filter all the available information for a random number of "numero de servicio". In the data I have the consume values for the clients("numero de servicio") for different dates, so what i want is to select randomly a sample of 5 clients and get their behavior in the time ( show all the dates and "consumo" values available

Comment: Is this giving you 2 samples the way you want? `serie_consumo.sample(2)` If not please explain what is missing. If you already have a list of numero de servicio that you want to sample then `lst = [400000102416, 400000102417] ` try `serie_consumo[serie_consumo['numero_servicio'].isin(lst)]`

Comment: I have 119297 diferent numbers of service "numero the servicios" and each "numero de servicio" has the information of consume "consumo" by month for some years. What I want since Im working with time series is to reduce the number of time series ( since each numero de servicio represents a time serie) to continue working and try some clustering algorith but with less information in order to advance faster